# Maven dependency tree with repository info

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I like to get a dependency tree (e.g. [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html)) which list all transitive dependencies of my maven project, along with the information from which maven repository the dependency has been pulled.

The problem is that dependencies can bring in their own repositories and I like to identify which dependency has been pulled from which repository.

Currently I need to start with a cleared maven cache and filter the `mvn` output for "[INFO] Downloaded from …", but I hope there is a better way.